# Como tipar chaves (keys) de objetos aninhados no Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tipagem

Eu preciso que o tipo `ColumnDefinitionType` aceite as chaves do objeto `IUser`, bem como aceite as chaves de objetos aninhados ao `IUser`.

```
export interface IUser {
  userId: number;
  username: string;
  name: string;
  firstAccess: number;

  status: number;
  profile: {
    profileId: number;

    role: string;
  };
}


export type ColumnDefinitionType<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  key: K;
  header: string;
  width?: number;
};



const columns: ColumnDefinitionType<IUser, keyof IUser>[] = [
  {
    key: 'name',
    header: 'Nome',
    width: 150
  }
]
```

No caso, a constante `columns` aceita a chave `name` na propriedade `key`, mas não consigo passar para ela a chave `role` existente em `user.profile.role`, sendo assim gostaria de saber como estender essa minha tipagem de `ColumnDefinitionType`.

Comment: Isso acontece porque `role` não é uma chave de `IUser`. Como ficaria o `key`? `"profile.role"`?

Comment: Exatamente Luiz, ele não aceita por não ser chave de IUser, então preciso saber se há algum modo de ajustar meu ColumnDefinitionType para aceitar as chaves de objetos aninhados. Seja passando diretamente 'role' ou conforme você mencionou 'profile.role'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Penso que não seja possível fazer isso com arrays (pelo menos não de forma *simples*) porque o compilador não tem como saber o tipo do elemento associado a uma chave específica para cada elemento do array. Ele formaria uma união com todos os tipos possíveis.

Mas é possível fazer uma estrutura com objetos. Algo como isto:

```
export interface IUser {
  userId: number;
  profile: {
    profileId: number;
  };
}

const columns: ColumnDefinitionType<IUser> = {
  userId: {
    header: 'ID do usuário',
    width: 50
  },
  profile: {
    subColumns: {
      profileId: {
        header: 'ID do perfil',
        width: 50
      }
    }
  }
};
```

<sup>Note que removi alguns campos para simplificar o exemplo.</sup>

Trata-se de uma estrutura "recursiva". E, justamente por isso, precisamos criar um tipo recursivo para o caso de objetos aninhados ao objeto principal. Para isso, pode-se utilizar tipos condicionais.

Veja:

```
export type BareColumn = {
  header: string;
  width: number;
};

export type ColumnDefinitionType<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object
    ? { subColumns: ColumnDefinitionType<T[K]> } // Note que este tipo é recursivo para objetos.
    : BareColumn;
};
```

Basicamente, tem-se um [*mapped type*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) que mapeia cada propriedade do objeto `T` para um novo tipo. Esse novo tipo é determinado através de um [tipo condicional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), de modo que:

- Se o tipo do elemento atual for `object` (qualquer valor não primitivo), utilize um objeto que chama novamente o tipo `ColumnDefinitionType`, passando o objeto atual (o que cria uma "estrutura" recursiva).
- Caso contrário, infere-se que se trata de um tipo primitivo (não `object`) e utiliza-se o tipo `BareColumn` (que contém informações simples para uma coluna sem "filhos").

Desse modo, ao invés de se ter um array com informações de cada coluna, tem-se um objeto, no qual as chaves representam a própria `key` (que antes era uma propriedade de cada elemento do array).

Não creio que será uma limitação tão grande, mas isso é suposição minha. Talvez isso sirva de caminho.

Deixei o exemplo completo no **[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFUBnNOAbwFgAoOOAV1KnwBMAuOJegWwCM0A3DTpgoEdAgA2wDlVp04o8VOCsOXPoOFwAvkOo6aNUJFhwYATzB4AQpijAAwhEk8kcALwVtAC2CYWNA5iGChkAHN9OgB3BBYYH3Uefih9PSNqE2h4S2s4Z1duJAARYAkkBBgECCQAFStgAB5agD5Pb3kAbQBpRHcAa2ALcThagF0OWp6xuFBUJBZiOAheACtgbBhtOgB%20Cjhiel4Ct2IOE6LS8srquobm6badOAB6F7gAOQhUOABHejwwBCeCqkDgAEu4A5sPQoMQEAA3CCKeyYZZrYAwCDEAB02zgHDsDguSDS%20ho2BqITglMKSDO%20RcbiuyBuNXq1kaRCYbS8cjojDQag6CjgfgCQTgAHJ8MU4CxkYx6ABDsIQKUAGnxsXiiTgAFYAAzaHRa%20RKCTSWT4w7HJlFBn80WKMSW1TsEXOujiwJQDgyuUKxRoS2a-GinUJDhG8O6fGGeQJ9LUIA)**.